# How to use pagination in codeigniter with segments?

Tags: php, codeigniter, pagination

I have one problem in Codeigniter pagination with segments. I need to pass segments with page number.

Example: http://www.mysite.com/app/controller/method/param1/param2/page_number

```
<?php

$this->load->library('pagination');
$config['base_url'] = 'http://localhost/welcome/par1/para2/';
$config['total_rows'] = 200;
$config['per_page'] = 20;

$this->pagination->initialize($config);

echo $this->pagination->create_links();

?>
```

Comment: base_url is always same or each time you need current page url ?

Comment: Are those parameteres dynamic? or are always 2?

Comment: dynamic so i got problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the URL helper function current_url() as your base url.

From the CI documentation (http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/helpers/url_helper.html):

> current_url() -
>   Returns the full URL (including segments) of the page being currently viewed.

So, in your situation, the controller would look like this:

```
$this->load->library('pagination');
$config['base_url'] = current_url();
$config['total_rows'] = 200;
$config['per_page'] = 20;

$this->pagination->initialize($config);

echo $this->pagination->create_links();
```

This method should allow you to have as many parameters as you need.